# How to accommodate 100 columns in a single report?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

**Requirement**:

I have one new requirement in Crystal Reports.

I need to show 100 columns in the report. I have tried using Landscape option but maximum I am able to accommodate are 20 columns.

Can someone have any idea on how can I accommodate 100 columns. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use (a) a smaller font, or (b) a larger paper format ....

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks for your reply. Can you please explain more about this.

Comment: Well, sorry, but this is a silly requirement - you can fit only so much information on a page. Period. Either your boss needs to trim down the report to as many columns as you can fit on a page, or you need to use a really large paper size, or you need to print sooooo small that you can fit those 100 columns on a regular page.....

Comment: @marc_s: I understand it's really funny requirement but I need to fit the columns.

Comment: As I said already: in that case, you just need to use a really really small font, e.g. "Arial 3pt" ....... nobody will be able to actually **read** and use that report - but you'll have your 100 columns on the page. ....

Comment: This requirement would only make sense if the report is *not being printed* (I don't think anyone is expecting you to fit 100 columns on a printable page) and in which case you can just make the size of paper/canvas as large as you want.

Comment: @Ryan:Report is not for print purpose. Customer export the the data into excel and he do the validations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Practically it is not suggested to take 100 columns..as this can create an issue while monitoring the data in crystal reports`

But if you still need to accompdate the 100 columns then follow below process.

go to `File --> Page Setup --> there go to Unit --> for selected option give maximun size for Horizontal Component`

This will increase the size of the report and now can insert required number of columns

Answer (score 1):

Since this report is not for print and will be exported into an Excel format, just make your page as big as you need it. This can be done by going to "File" → "Page Setup" and adjusting the following things:

1. Check "Dissociate Formatting Page Size and Printer Paper Size"
2. Might as well flip the page to "Landscape"
3. Enter a large number in "Horizontal"

You should also note that because you're exporting this data (especially as "Excel - Data Only"), you don't need to make the columns wide enough to display; as long as the field is on the canvas they should show up as a column.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the columns doesn't matter if you are going to export to Excel data only. So you can make the columns as small as you want, even if the report is not readable it will be exported OK.

If you want just to export some data and your report does not include subreports you can go without Crystal reports. Will be much simpler to set the SQL and preview data in a grid (which is scrollable) and then export it to Excel. It will look better too.
There are some tools that can do this and I guess you can easily find something on Google. I am using R-Tag (www.r-tag.com), which is free. You can see it in action here: http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/Preview_Demo.aspx